# gradle.properties not taking values from command line

Tags: jenkins, gradle, command-line, system-properties, gradle-properties

I have gradle.properties file for which I am passing value from command line as below command but not taking the value.

> gradle test -DsystemProp.RunnerApplication=QAEnv -Dgroups=CSP-Smoke

My build.gradle file code as follows-

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
        classpath group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8.+'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
group 'org.csp.xxxx'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {

    systemProperty "RunnerApplication",System.getProperty("RunnerApplication")

    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("test-output/reports/")
    }
    def Coregroups = System.getProperty('groups','Core-Smoke \n CSP-Smoke')
    useTestNG()
            {
                includeGroups Coregroups
                useDefaultListeners = true
                options.suites("src/test/java/TestAPISuite.xml")
                //options.listeners << 'com.ddddd.smsApi.qa.framework.listener.CustomListener'
                //options.listeners << 'com.dddd.smsApi.qa.framework.listener.EmailListener'
                options.listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
                options.listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
                systemProperty 'org.uncommons.reportng.title', 'csp_api_automation_results'
            }
    testLogging.events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    testLogging.exceptionFormat = "full"
    //Interceptors
    beforeTest { desc ->
        println "\n*** Starting execution of test ${desc.className}.${desc.name} ***"
    }
    afterTest { descriptor, result ->
        println "<<< Test ${descriptor.name} resulted in ${result.resultType} and took "+getElaspedTime(result.endTime - result.startTime)+" >>>\n"
    }
    //Modify the test logging
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        runtimeClasspath = files(output.resourcesDir) + runtimeClasspath
    }
    test {
        runtimeClasspath = files(output.resourcesDir) + runtimeClasspath
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '3.0.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8.+'
    //An assertion library that is better than JUnit defaults
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0M10'
    //Better reporting for testng.  It outputs a nice html report
    testCompile 'org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.15'
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.htmlcompressor', name: 'htmlcompressor', version: '1.5.2'
    compile group: 'commons-dbutils', name: 'commons-dbutils', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'
    compile group: "com.github.fge", name: "json-schema-validator", version: "2.2.6"
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.guice-repository', name: 'guice-repository', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.easytesting', name: 'fest-assert-core', version: '2.0M10'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: '1.3'
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'
    compileClasspath group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8.+'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cedarsoftware/json-io
    compile group: 'com.cedarsoftware', name: 'json-io', version: '2.6.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.17'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports
    compile group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports', version: '4.0.9'
}
def getElaspedTime(def time) {
    if(time / 1000 < 1)
    {
        return String.format("0 min, %.3f sec", time/1000)
    }
    else
    {
        return String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(time) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time))
        )
    }
}
```

systemProp.RunnerApplication=dev is the key and value saved in my gradle.properties.
Here I want to run as RunnerApplication=QAEnv so automation can run in different environments

But its is always running on dev even Passing QAEnv in command line.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you get any solutions for your problems ?  As i am also new to gradle and trying many ways to find the solution for my problems.

Comment: Can you get connected on gmail to discuss further :  baluzen@gmail.com  mobile : 8884479958

Comment: Yes, I have fixed this issue. Do you have a connection link?

Comment: No dont have a link. Can you please share the same and if provided please discuss the same through call also.

Comment: Can you please also tell me how to just execute/run the cucumber runner file through gradle build as we do normally with maven or we just do like usually run the TestNGCucumberRunner.java in IntelliJ /eclipse by right-click and it runs successfully. My intent is to Invoke the TestNGCucumberRunner.java in gradle
and

Invoke all the features in gradle and at the end reports generated

Comment: Please create a question so I can answer on it. Please share the question link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745230/i-need-to-have-an-gradle-task-to-execute-my-cucumber-runner-class-and-execute-cu

Comment: : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745365/how-could-i-create-a-gradle-task-to-perform-logging-using-log4j

Comment: I need to invoke Cucumber Runner through gradle and which in turn does all the test execution and reporting also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765077/i-need-to-invoke-cucumber-runner-through-gradle-and-which-in-turn-does-all-the-t

Comment: Any update on the above queston

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y I have answered to your question Link. Please check and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in two system properties. One is prefixed with `systemProp.` and the other isn't. This should indicate to you that one of them is wrong. And it's the former :)

There is a use for the `systemProp.` prefix, but only when declaring system properties through the `gradle.properties` file. Here, you are declaring them from the command line.

So instead of:

`gradle test -DsystemProp.RunnerApplication=QAEnv -Dgroups=CSP-Smoke`

Run:

`gradle test -DRunnerApplication=QAEnv -Dgroups=CSP-Smoke`

Comment: I used gradle test -DRunnerApplication=QAEnv -Dgroups=CSP-Smoke, didnt work. Still runs on dev instead of QAEnv. Also gradle.properties contains- systemProp.RunnerApplication=dev