# I need to invoke Cucumber Runner through gradle and which in turn does all the test execution and reporting also

Tags: gradle, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-jvm

I am not sure whether we can  run the cucumber runner class which in turn runs all the tests and does even the reporting part also.

Just like in Cucumber Maven project we run the Cucumber runner file to execute the tests and even generates the reports after run in the same context is it doable in gradle by calling the Cucumber runner class.

My cucumber runner is as below

```
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;


     @CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:featurefile" }, glue = { "classpath:com.hals.brands.test.stepdefinition",
            "classpath:com.hals.brands.helper" }, plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/HalsprosBrands.json",
                    "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" }, monochrome = true, tags = "@Api")
    
    
    public class **HalProsbrandsTestRunner** extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    
        
        @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
        public static void writeExtentReport() {
                
            ReporterUtil.archiveReport();
            
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    package runners;
    
    import com.cucumber.listener.ExtentProperties;
    import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;
    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import stepDefinations.Hooks;
    
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = ".//test//java//FeatureList",glue = "stepDefinations",
            plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:",
                    "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml"},
            tags="@Smoke-Login",
            monochrome = true
    )
    public class TestRunner {
    
        @BeforeClass
        public static void setup(){
            //Initializing extent reporting here
}
}
```

Here I am basically initializing my cucumber feature and class definition.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.mytest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    //junit
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.10'
    //cucumber
    compileOnly 'info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.5'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'gherkin', version: '2.12.2'
    compile group: 'net.masterthought', name: 'cucumber-reporting', version: '3.18.0'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '1.2.4'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.4'
    //reporting
    compile 'com.vimalselvam:cucumber-extentsreport:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.aventstack:extentreports:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.aventstack:extentreports:3.1.2'
    //logger
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    //selenium
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.14.0'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-remote-driver', version: '3.14.0'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.14.0'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: '3.14.0'
    //compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: '2.53.1'

}

test {
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = false
    }
    testLogging {
        events 'passed', 'failed', 'standardError'
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Here to run this- you need to use the command

> gradle build or test

command needs to be run in terminal.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: For my case this does`nt work . My setup is bit different  I figured it out with Cucumber task where i include the glue, featurefile and have used ExtentCucumberAdapter for reports. Now its working fne only thing is logging is not working i mean logs are written to log file

Comment: Anyways thanks for reply and would appreciate you helping me on the logging part. for logging iam using Log4j